# Need help to find outlier in longitudinal data using sas

Tags: sas, proc, mixed

I have a classroom of students with test scores taken weekly. I expect the test results to improve over time. I want to identify a poor performer as an outlier based on not improving over time using SAS (have 9.2). Also are there accepted criteria for being an outlier for part of the time interval but not the complete time interval? This is the bulk of my present code (not looking for outliers yet, just longitudinal analysis):

```
proc mixed data= XYZ_LONG ;
title1 'XYZ Analysis';
class group day subject ;
model TV = group day group*day / ddfm=satterthwaite;
repeated day / type = cs sub = subject ;
```

Comment: Maybe start by defining outlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of "poor performer" is not a definition of outlier, I don't think. However:

If you want to find people who did not improve over time, that's pretty easy, but you have to define it more precisely.  Did not improve between *any* two weeks?  The *first and last* weeks? Something else?

And what do you mean by "not improve" exactly? Do you mean it literally (same or worse score at later time?)

In either case, I'd use an array and find difference scores and then identify difference scores that were negative (or whatever you want).

However, if you are going to be doing modelling, then an outlier should probably be defined in terms of that model - that is, in your model, accounting for group.  But if you have a lot of outliers and they aren't bad data, you should not throw out those people, but use a better model.